# Restoring OAuth 2 authenticated sessions

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-docs-api

I am successfully using OAuth 2 to authenticate my console app against
Google's Doc service (thanks to the good samaritans on this list).
Problem obviously being that a user has to authenticate every time
they use the app.

Is it possible to save the authorised token (I have done this with
three legged OAuth) and restore it for subsequent uses of my
application?

I am documenting my experiences here, incase anyone is hunting down
the solution to the problems I am having
http://code.google.com/p/gdatacopier/wiki/DevelopmentNotes30

Thanks for your time.

PS Documentation on this is quite sparse in the Googleverse.

Comment: All of that is actually very well documented in the [actual OAuth 2 spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2)

Answer (score 3):

When you authorize a user, you should ask for [`offline` access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline). This gives you a refresh token that you can later use to [restore an access token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) for use in the API. You should store this refresh token.

Comment: Thanks Ali, are you aware of any GDoc Python API client examples?

Comment: GAM - Google Apps Manager is an open source python project that does oath storage of the token in a file. You can consult the source here http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/